# In Britain, can the "address" part of a "printer's imprint" consist only of their email address?

Tags: united-kingdom, publishing

In Britain it is obligatory [*] for printed publications of many kinds to include the printer's name and address. Can the address be the printer's email address, or does it have to be their street address?

Notes
* Printer's Imprint Act 1961; Newspapers, Printers, and Reading Rooms Repeal Act 1869.

Comment: An email address is not acceptable as an imprint address.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHarvey . Please can you cite a source. If you do then you will have answered the question and I will be grateful, but I can only give you the green tick if you post the information as a formal answer rather than in a comment.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - What forms do you think are acceptable as an imprint address and why? I have many books published by well-known publishers in which the imprint does not specify the printer's full postal address.